# Multiple Attribute Selector FIND

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder, when returning an object. Do a find, but it turns out I have 2 ids to check ... It just returns the 1st ID:

```
$(date).find('#l_1, #L_2').each(function(index, value){
value = $(value).html();
$('#return').append(value);
});


<div id="l_1"></div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
  <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>

<div id="l_1"></div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="l_3"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>

<div id="l_1"></div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="l_3"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>

<div id="l_1"></div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
<div id="L_2">
   <div class="else"></div>
   <div class="else"></div>
</div>
```

Also, check that the first element below the # l_1 in case the # L_2 possess in its first element a class .l_3 if it has I have to jump all # L_2 until the next # l_1.

How can I do this?

Comment: ID must be UNIQUE and once in page for javascript. You should use any other selector if is multiply

Comment: The problem is that I give a POST and caught with CURL page of a website, where they only use IDs in divs, this refers DATA (DOM) to a page of a site ...

Comment: That CURL comment is unintelligible...what does it mean? This whole question needs quite a bit of clarification updated in the question itself. Proper sentences would also help

Comment: Desculpe, a tradução eu não entendi direito. Eu pego uma página web com CURL, esta página é semelhante à questão do HTML. Talves algo, ajudar a separar: `$(data+'#l_1 :first').nextUntil("#l_2 :last").html(); `Understand something, help separates only those IDs DOM ...